# If I buy certain-sized filter system, for example a 150mm holder, which size filters can I use for it?

Tags: lens, filters

Would they have to be strictly 150mmx150mm holders? Or could they also be rectangular, such as 150mmx100mm for example?

Sorry for the basic question - I'm pretty new to filters and its peripherals.

Answer (score 2):

Filter holders are designed to be used with filters that are the same width as the size of the holder and *at least as long* as the size of the holder.

Filters for a 150mm holder need to be 150 x ≥150 mm.
Filters for a 100mm holder need to be 100 x ≥100 mm.
Filters for an 84mm holder need to be 84 x ≥84 mm.

[image]
 <sub>Comparative sizes of the Cokin A Series (67mm), P Series (84mm), Z-Pro Series (100mm), and X-Pro Series (130mm) filter systems.</sub>

The major exception are circular polarizer filters. These filters are circular in shape and need to be made to fit in a specific holder.

A CPL, including the ring it is mounted in, for a 150mm holder will be 150mm in diameter.
A CPL, including the ring it is mounted in, for a 100mm holder will be 100mm in diameter.
A CPL, including the ring it is mounted in, for an 84mm holder will be 84mm in diameter.

[image]

When using your 150mm filter system with the lens which requires a filter of that size, the minimum usable filter size is 150 x 150 mm. Any filter the correct thickness for your holder that is 150mm on the shortest side can be used in a 150mm holder. 150 x 170 mm is a common size. **But you could also use any 150 x ≥150 mm filter.** 150 x 150 mm? Check. 150 x 170 mm? Check. 150 x 200 mm, 150 x 151 mm, or 150 x 300 mm? Check, check, and check.

If you later decide to use a 150mm holder and adapter rings with a lens that doesn't require that much coverage, it *might* be possible to use 150 x 100 mm filters with such a lens that has a narrower field of view. In practice, though, it wouldn't be very useful.

Why?

Because most 150 x 100 mm filters are *graduated* filters that are darker in some places and lighter in other places. They are made to be used in 100mm filter holders.

[image]

The extra 50mm gives the user room to slide the filter up or down in the holder to adjust exactly where in the frame the transition line on the filter is. If you put a 150 x 100 mm filter in a 150mm holder, it will be sideways and the direction you can slide it will be along the same axis as the graduation on the filter. Plus, since the filter is only 100mm in the other dimension, you couldn't move it very far anyway before the edge would be inside the field of view of a lens that needs 100mm filters. With a lens that needs a 150mm filter holder, *both* edges of the 150 x 100mm filter would be inside the lens' field of view.

[This video from B&H](https://youtu.be/Fcxzx8U69xA?t=5m19s) gives an overview about using neutral density (ND) filters. The section about holders and square filters starts at the 5:20 mark in the video. Seeing how the filters slide in and out of the holder should help you better visualize how it all works.

Answer (score 1):

150mm holder is for 150mm filters. If you put 150x100 filter on such holder you will see above and/or below band not covered by filter. The filters (as far as I know) which are usually used with 150mm holder are 150x150 and 150x170

And take in consideration 150mm holders are (usually) for wide-angle lens like Nikon 14-24, Canon 14, Canon TS-E 17, Tamron 15-30 and similar.

Comment: Yeah, it's for a 14mm lens I'll be using. Thank you very much. So it's 150x150 and 150x170 I strictly need to be looking for only?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh, those sizes I know. For sure there are manufacturers which build different sizes :) But all will be 150x150+something

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So if the system I'm considering is for a thickness of 2mm, will any filters I buy need to strictly be 2mm thick too?

Comment: It should have thickness no more than 2mm. Probably 1.5mm will be fine. But 1mm may not fit well. The good (and most of the time expensive) rule is to buy filters from holder manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

The square filter holder grabs onto the filter *at the sides*. The brackets are, per your example, 150mm apart. The brackets have a depth that they are willing to accommodate, usually in the 2 or 3mm mark (thickness of the filter).

So, for a filter to fit, it must be at least thick enough to be secure in the holder, must touch both sides (thus being 150mm in width), and can be any length, but must be *at least* 150mm in order to cover the front of the lens.

You'll find that, for a 150mm system, most of the filters you buy will be 150mm X 150mm square. There's an exception here for graduated ND's - which may be longer in length (and because of this, allow you to more accurately position where the gradient begins and how strongly it's effects are in the picture).

Comment: Thank you, Corey. What sort of lengths are we talking for grad NDs? So the filters I buy can be any length so long as they're 150mm in width to touch both sides? So would, for example, a 150x100 filter be suitable in a 150mm system?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh I would doubt it. The filter needs to cover the entire viewing angle of the lens, otherwise part of your shot would be covered by filter and part wouldn't be. 150x100 *might* work, but then again, it might not. Best find a seller with a good return policy if you want to experiment.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not in the best company for this example. Buyers of the 14mm Samyang are a small market and it's a small percent of that who purchase filter kits for it. You're going to have to bite the bullet at some point and experiment on your own.